# how to add png for a image in code for silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

Try to create a image in code as below:

```
sp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
Image myImage = new Image() { HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, Width = 16, Height = 16, Margin = new Thickness(1, 0, 0, 0) };
MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyAssembly;component/folder/image1.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
sp.Children.Add(MyImage);
```

then run the app, the image does not display. Check the data with Fiddler and got 404 error. The source for above image is something like:

```
http://localhost:80/MyAssembly;component/folder/image1.png
```

but this image is complied into an assembly MyAssembly.

It is okay to get the image xaml from the assembly with following markup:

```
<Image Source="/MyAssembly;component/folder/image1.png"/>
```

Confused. Not sure why. How to get dynamic image in code?

**Updated:** Thanks for information form Clemens. Try following code:

```
sp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
ImageSourceConverter converter = new ImageSourceConverter();
Image myImage = new Image() { HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, Width = 16, Height = 16, Margin = new Thickness(1, 0, 0, 0) }; 
MyImage.Source = (ImageSource)converter.ConvertFromString("/MyAssembly;component/folder/image1.png");
sp.Children.Add(MyImage);
```

the result same as before. message from Fiddler:
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

The resource for this still is

```
 http://localhost:80/MyAssembly;component/folder/image1.png.
```

Comment: You could try to set the image as source in XAML, then copy/paste the proper URI.

Comment: Oh, and check the compile action of your image, what is it currently?

Comment: And it really works (as you wrote) if you set it in XAML like `<Image Source="/MyAssembly;component/folder/image1.png"/>`? That's strange. Did you rebuild both the Silverlight application and the host application?

Comment: Came along this again. Maybe the edited answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what scheme to use for that Uri in Silverlight, where you would write something like `pack://application,,,/MyAssembly;component/folder/image1.png` in WPF.

But fortunately you could always write this:

```
ImageSourceConverter converter = new ImageSourceConverter();
MyImage.Source = (ImageSource)converter.ConvertFromString(
                     "/MyAssembly;component/folder/image1.png");
```

It is of course also possible to explicitly set a relative URI:

```
MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(
    new Uri("/MyAssembly;component/folder/image1.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Note however that the [Build Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx) for `image1.png` has to be set to `Resource` in any case.